# R - Fast rowsum matrix of every n-th element

Tags: r, matrix

I have a problem, regarding a fast summing over rows for every n-th element.

Consider a matrix with 16 columns and m rows. The result should have 4 columns and m rows, where each column is a sum every nth elements, i.e., the first column is the sum of columns 1,5,9,13, the second of 2,6,10,14 ... .

Currently I am realizing this by doing a matrix multiplication. However, for large matrices, this takes too long. The posted solutions only sum over n consecutive elements in a row, not split up.

/edit:
Here the way I am currently solving it:

```
test <- matrix(c(1:24000),ncol=64)

SumFeatures <- function(ncol,nthElement) {
  ncolRes <- ncol/nthElement
  matrix(c(rep(diag(ncolRes),times = nthElement)),ncol = ncolRes,byrow = TRUE)
}

# Get Matrix to sum over every 4th element
sumMatrix <- SumFeatures(ncol(test),4)

system.time(test %*% sumMatrix)
```

Is there a fast solution, to solve this issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: Could you please provide some data so we can help you out? See here for a minimal reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Using as input the matrix `m` derived from the built-in 11 by 8 data.frame `anscombe`:

```
# create test matrix m
m <- as.matrix(anscombe)
```

**1) apply/tapply** Try this:

```
t(apply(m, 1, tapply, gl(4, 1, ncol(m)), sum))
```

giving:

```
          1     2     3     4
 [1,] 18.04 19.14 17.46 14.58
 [2,] 14.95 16.14 14.77 13.76
 [3,] 20.58 21.74 25.74 15.71
 [4,] 17.81 17.77 16.11 16.84
 [5,] 19.33 20.26 18.81 16.47
 [6,] 23.96 22.10 22.84 15.04
 [7,] 13.24 12.13 12.08 13.25
 [8,]  8.26  7.10  9.39 31.50
 [9,] 22.84 21.13 20.15 13.56
[10,] 11.82 14.26 13.42 15.91
[11,] 10.68  9.74 10.73 14.89
```

**2) tapply** or this giving the same result:

```
do.call(cbind, tapply(1:ncol(m), gl(4, 1, ncol(m)), function(ix) rowSums(m[, ix])))
```

**3) tapply - 2** or this which gives a similar result:

```
matrix(tapply(m, gl(4 * nrow(m), 1, length(m)), sum), nrow(m))
```

**4) apply/array** or this which additionally requires that there be the same number of input columns summed into each of the output columns:

```
apply(array(m, c(nrow(m), 4, ncol(m) / 4)), 1:2, sum)
```

Note that this is just `apply(array(m, c(11, 4, 2), 1:2, sum)` in the case of `m`.

**5) for** This alternative is based on a `for` loop:

```
res <- 0
for(i in seq(1, ncol(m), 4)) res <- res + m[, seq(i, length = 4)]
res
```

It would be possible to speed this up even more by setting res to m[, 1:4] and then starting i at 4+1 but the code gets a bit uglier so we will not bother.

**6) Reduce**

```
matrix(Reduce("+", split(m, gl(ncol(m) / 4, nrow(m) * 4))), nrow(m))
```

**7) rowsum**

```
t(rowsum(t(m), gl(4, 1, ncol(m))))
```

**Note:** Of the solutions tested below

- (6), (5) and (4) are the fastest in descending order of speed (i.e. (6) is fastest).  These three also require that the number of columns of `m` be an even multiple of 4. (2) is the fastest of the solutions that do not require an even multiple followed by (3), (7) and (1) where (1) is the slowest.
- (7) is the shortest, (1) is the next shortest and (4) is the third shortest

Here is the benchmark:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  one = t(apply(m, 1, tapply, gl(4, 1, ncol(m)), sum)),
  two = do.call(cbind, 
         tapply(1:ncol(m), gl(4, 1, ncol(m)), function(ix) rowSums(m[, ix]))),
  three = matrix(tapply(m, gl(4 * nrow(m), 1, length(m)), sum), nrow(m)), 
  four = apply(array(m, c(nrow(m), 4, ncol(m) / 4)), 1:2, sum),
  five = {res <- 0
          for(i in seq(1, ncol(m), 4)) res <- res + m[, seq(i, length = 4)]
          res },
  six = matrix(Reduce("+", split(m, gl(ncol(m) / 4, nrow(m) * 4))), nrow(m)),
  seven = t(rowsum(t(m), gl(4, 1, ncol(m)))),
  order = "relative", replications = 1000)[1:4]
```

giving:

```
   test replications elapsed relative
6   six         1000    0.12    1.000
5  five         1000    0.18    1.500
4  four         1000    0.30    2.500
2   two         1000    0.31    2.583
3 three         1000    0.39    3.250
7 seven         1000    0.58    4.833
1   one         1000    2.27   18.917
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the absolute fastest computation speeds are achieved when you reduce the problem to an operation between two 1-dimensional arrays that are contiguous in memory.  This usually involves reshaping your data, which can be an expensive operation, but it pays off if you need to repeat the calculation a number of times.

Using an 11 × 8 matrix as an example (the same as in G. Grothendieck's solution), I would do

```
dim(m) <- c(44, 2)
out <- m[, 1] + m[, 2]
dim(out) <- c(11, 4)
```

Keep in mind that when reshaping an array, `t()` and `aperm()` make a copy of the data and therefore are slow, whereas changing the `dim` attribute is fast.